# Are there any differences between $\textrm{Aut}(G)$ and $\textrm{Sym}(G)$ for a group $G$, or are the two notations synonymous?

Tags: group-theory, notation, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group

I have seen both notations--- $\textrm{Aut}(G)$ and $\textrm{Sym}(G)$---for a group $G$, and they seem to denote the same thing: the group of all bijections on $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every automorphism is a bijection; but the converse is not true.  Automorphisms need to be homomorphisms in addition to being bijections.  For example, if a bijection does not take the identity element to itself, it can't be an automorphism.

Answer (score 3):

If I had to guess, $\text{Aut}(G)$ is the automorphism group of $G$, while $\text{Sym}(G)$ is the symmetric group on the underlying set of $G$ (a.k.a. the group of all bijections $G \to G$). If $G$ is any nontrivial group, $\text{Aut}(G)$ is a proper subgroup of $\text{Sym}(G)$. You should really look up the conventions in whatever you're reading to make sure they agree with mine.

Comment: These are also the conventions I would use.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the maps $l_a: x\mapsto ax$ and $c_a: x\mapsto a^{-1}xa$, where $a$ is a given, non-identity element of $G$. Both are bijections on $G$, but $c_a$ has in addition the operation-preserving property, $c_a(xy)=c_a(x)c_a(y)$ for every $x,y\in G$, which $l_a$ hasn't. So, both are elements of $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$, but $c_a$ only is an element of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: How about "is an element of" instead of "stays in"?  Good answer though.  Also, by "nonunit" element, I take it you mean "non-identity".

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @Chris Custer. Well noted and edited accordingly.